# Printing the correct date value in a view

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type with a Date CCK field that prints the correct date/time specified in nodes (using the correct timezone, format, etc.). I also created a view that uses this date field, but the time I am getting from the view date data is (+)4 hours off. The date information is being printed in a views template using the `$row` object (specifically, the `raw` array key inside of the date field array). This array provides the 'to' and 'from' dates (and time), the timezone, and all other relevant information, but the values are 4 hours off as I said above.

Is there something I need to do when printing these kinds of values in a view in order to get the correct time? I'm assuming the Date module does some sort of processing that the views data isn't getting. Any guidance would be great because I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double check that your **site's timezone** is accurate at: Site Configuration > Date & Time
2. Double check that your **user timezone** is accurate in your profile. Perhaps turn off user timezones (on the same admin pages as above.)
3. Confirm how timezones are handled on the specific **CCK field.** There are 5 options:
   Site's time zone, Date's time zone, User's time zone, UTC, and No time zone conversion.

Comment: I actually just ended up doing this: `date('g:iA',strtotime($the_date_string) - 14400);`. The Date module does something to the values once it pulls them from the database, but I'm not completely sure what.

Comment: As you probably know that solution is not the *right* one. Something I've also seen is that a server date can be set wrong, or in another timezone. If your site's timezone just takes the server timezone weirdness can happen. The above stuff I mentioned should allow you to correct any weirdness. I promise that the data module isn't just adding the 4 hours for no reason :)